# In React, How to Import Component from webpack bundle directly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

In normal condition, we import component from another JavaScript file. However, in my project, I want to import component from the bundle created by webpack.

**Step 1:**
Create a bundle of ABC folder, named as abc.bundle.js

Note: ABC folder has files a.js, b.js, c.js and has components a,b,c respectively

**Step 2:**
Inside the DEF folder, write file DEF.js as following

Note: Importing "a" component from a.js **works fine**

```
import react from 'react'
import a from './abc/a.js'
```

**Step 3:**
Inside the DEF folder, write file DEF.js as following

Note: Importing "a" component from abc.bundle.js, **it gives error**

```
import react from 'react'
import a from 'abc.bundle.js'
```

According to me and my team, We can import component from the bundle. because

```
 1) The bundle is a js file, and we can import one code from one js file to another
 2) Node modules packages are also get created by webpack, and we can import functionalities from that package.
```

Comment: Did you find a way to load the components from webpack bundles .?

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile the `abc` folder as a standalone library module with Webpack, and then you can import it. You can then either publish it to npm, and use it like any other 3rd party module, or just publish it to a folder within your parent project (maybe using a monorepo structure).

The Webpack `library` and `libraryTarget` options are worth looking at:

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-library
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-librarytarget

Alternatively there are tools to help you with this sort of thing:

https://github.com/insin/nwb

E.g.

https://github.com/insin/nwb/blob/master/docs/guides/ReactComponents.md#developing-react-components-and-libraries-with-nwb

Comment: I had set output library target as 'var' and now want to import it with scriptjs, can you tell me how to import this component I am able to to import and print it and prints object but not able to use it.

Comment: same here...set target as 'var', imported bundles js script in client app, able to print out object adn even call functions from bundle but not able to render React components from it. Anyone figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/

Webpack provides different targets for bundling. Depends on how you configure your webpack's config, you can use the bundle files in different environments.

I believe your bundle's target is `web`, since it's the default one. To make it usable in Node environment, you need to set target to `node`